# In Visual Studios 2013 is there some sort of resource monitor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

Me and my friends compete in how efficient our C++ code is, and I was wondering if there is any way to measure how many calculations our code is performing and how much memory it takes up. Not sure if stack overflow is the correct place to ask this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I figured I'd answer in case others ask the same.
I use VS 2015 and there is a very useful window called Diagnostic Tools.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/13/memory-usage-tool-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015/
To enable, go to Debug>Show Diagnostic Tools (or CTL + ALT + F2) and you memory usage will be displayed in real-time as you debug. 
To answer you question, it seems that VS 2013 had the performance and diagnostics hub.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/07/12/performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013/